# Render image within razor view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp.net mvc 5 application which communicates with a friendly api. So, I create this part of view :

```
<img src="@Html.Image(Model.Logo,25,25)" />
```

and I added a custom html helper to display the logo

```
   public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, byte[] byteArray, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        FileContentResult arrayTof;
        if(byteArray==null)
        {
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"); 

            var full = Path.Combine(root, "Content/events_medium.jpg");

            using (Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(full.ToString()))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byteArray = m.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        string result = "data:image/jpg;" + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        return result;
    }

        public static byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] myBytes, int newWidth, int newHeight)
        {
            byte[] imageArray = null;
            try
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream myMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myBytes);
                System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
                System.Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                System.IO.MemoryStream myResult = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return myResult.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return imageArray;

        }
```

I get as html result :

```
 <img src="data:image/jpg;/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAZABkAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAE+AagDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAgIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQCBQEGBwAI/8QAURAAAgECBAQEAwUEBgYG" />
```

[image]

So I need to know

1. Why the image is not rendered?
2. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: @downloader explain your reason plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `src` element only accepts a string, you have to supply a string to it. Giving a `FileContentResult` just causes it to do a `ToString` on the supplied result.

The best option you have now, if the image is not too big, is to give a data-URI.

Let your method return this string:

```
string result = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

Comment: I get this exception `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

Comment: ah ok I just add **base64** in this line and it works  `string result = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);`

Comment: Indeed. Found the same :) I shouldn't write from the top of my head.